# How to dynamically change code when sheet name is changed?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that combine the defined sheets from different workbooks and saves them to a separate workbook. Each workbook contains a sheet with the same name `MODEL`. This sheet has a combobox, this combobox is associated with the worksheet name like in code below:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Select Case Sheets("MODEL").Range("code_plant")
Case 1
Sheets("MODEL").Range("price_zero").Copy _
Destination:=Sheets("MODEL").Range("price_on_view")
End Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The problem arises when all the worksheets are combined together in one workbook and renamed. I need to fix my combobox macro that should after renaming refer to the current (renamed) sheet name. I was trying to use the following function but can't figure out how it may be include in my code in right way.

```
Function MySheet()
Application.Volatile
MySheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.CodeName
End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code as is sits in the worksheet holding the combobox. It automatically applies to the correct sheet without need for a name , no?

Comment: If you want the name of the sheet containing the combobox ComboBox1.Parent.Name

Answer (score 2):

Your `ComboBox1_Change` event is declared in the worksheet module, so you should be using the `Me` keyword in your code, to refer to the sheet, instead of finding the sheet by name with `Sheets("MODEL")`.

Change your event handlers, in each source sheet to look like this:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Select Case Me.Range("code_plant")
        Case 1
            Me.Range("price_zero").Copy _
                Destination:=Me.Range("price_on_view")
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your combobox is in the same sheet, you do not need to specify the sheetname or use anything else to qualify it. The range will point to `Activesheet` (*Where ComboBox1 resides*)  which is the `Sheets("MODEL")` or whatever it's new name is.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Select Case Range("code_plant")
        Case 1: Range("price_zero").Copy Range("price_on_view")
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Ordinarily `Range` would refer to the ActiveSheet, but in a Worksheet module, you're right, it calls the sheet's Range property. I just prepend `Me.` to make it more explicit.

Comment: And that is what I mentioned. One doesn't "need" to make it explicit :)